# How to get the output as dictionary stream - socket

Tags: ios, swift, stream

I am getting output as string. But the value is in key & value

```
            var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 4096)
        if ( aStream == inputStream){

            while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
                let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                if(len > 0){
                    let output  = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                    if (output != ""){
                        NSLog("server said: %@", output!)
                        receivingData = output as! String
                        delegate.socketReceiveData(responce: receivingData)
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

data is coming in dictionary but the object is in string can’t able to covert.
`output = {“password": "12345", "method": "login", "mail_id": "abc@gmail.com"}`from server
but output is string
how to read value of method, password etc...

Comment: is `output = ` also coming in the string or the string is `{“password": "12345", "method": "login", "mail_id": "abc@gmail.com"}`

Comment: the string is {“password": "12345", "method": "login", "mail_id": "abc@gmail.com"}.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON string `"{"password": "12345", "method": "login", "mail_id": "abc@gmail.com"}"`

And you can convert it to a dictionary as follow

```
let data = output!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

do {
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
  let dict = json as? [String: Any]
  let method = dict?["method"]
  print(method)
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```

You can also try
`jsonObject(with stream: InputStream, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any` method and supply your input stream to it

---

### Edit

Try this code as well

```
var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 4096)
if ( aStream == inputStream){
  
  while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
    let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
    if(len > 0){
      
      let data = Data(bytes: &buffer, count: buffer.count)
      
      do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        let dict = json as? [String: Any]
        let method = dict?["method"]
        print(method)
      }
      catch {
        print(error)
      }
      
//          if (output != ""){
//            NSLog("server said: %@", output!)
//            receivingData = output as! String
//            delegate.socketReceiveData(responce: receivingData)
//          }
      
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Show this error
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the console for this output `NSLog("server said: %@", output!)`. Seems like you've malformed json

Comment: server said: {"method_status":"right","method_name":"login","id":"1","name":"testuser","phone":"2147483647","mail_id":"abc@gmail.com","password":"12345","status":"1","created_at":"Fri Jun 24 2016 15:28:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}

Comment: Dear you have some special invisible characters in the string you can put your whole string here and see http://www.jsoneditoronline.org

Comment: Changed the acaii coding to utf8, please try that other wise directly convert bytes in nsdata and then see

Comment: UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Answer (score 0):

plz use this

```
let strf = "{\"name\":\"maan\"}"


        let data = strf.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

         do {
            guard let toddo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else
            {

                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }

            print(toddo);
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Getting this error
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}